# MySQL stops working after a few minutes every time

Tags: mysql, xampp

every time I start MySQL on XAMPP, after a few minutes, I can't use the database anymore. When I try to stop the MySQL from XAMPP control panel, I get this error:

```
1:42:31 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to stop MySQL app...
1:42:31 PM  [mysql]     There may be an error, return code: 13444432 -
```

And I tried to kill the `mysqld.exe` task from task manager, but it's not working. The only way to make it work is to restart my PC!

Comment: Did you do some changes in the config files? If that is so, what did you changed?

Comment: @RyffLe No, I did not.

Comment: Did you created a table and/or an user where it works fine. So if there was something wrong that can be cause this error. Outherwise, it sounds for me like a corrupted file or a mistake in the Database.

Comment: @RyffLe I'm just coding sometimes, and I don't edit the database, but this happens every time, no matter what. Even if I just start `MySQL` and do nothing!

Comment: Mhhh... Did you tried to install a second XAMPP server to test it? If the new installed Server works then the old one got some corrupted files in there. Just use for the installation an outher directory name.

Comment: @RyffLe This is the only XAMPP I installed after I reinstalled windows.